# get_post_meta for all keys brings back arrays, not single values

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post_id,'',true);
```

brings back all the meta values for $post_id but it returns an array for each value, as shown below:
[image]

I might expect this if I had set the third parameter - single - to false but it's set to true. I haven't found anything in the codex that talks about what exactly is returned when key is blank.

Does someone have to information here and know how I can get back all the keys with each key value being a single value instead of an array of values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:  This is by design, but does not appear to be documented in the Codex.

If you look at the true documentation (the source code), you will see that `get_post_meta` calls `get_metadata`.  By inspecting the code of `get_metadata`, we can see that if the `$meta_key` is not posted, then it returns the value before it evaluates if `$single` is set or not:

```
 // Previously, $meta_cache is set to the contents of the post meta data

 // Here you see if there is no key set, it just returns it all
 if ( ! $meta_key ) {
     return $meta_cache;
 }

 // It's not until later than $single becomes a factor
 if ( isset($meta_cache[$meta_key]) ) {
    if ( $single )
        return maybe_unserialize( $meta_cache[$meta_key][0] );
    else
        return array_map('maybe_unserialize', $meta_cache[$meta_key]);
 }
```

If you are using PHP 5.3+, you can get what you want with something like this:

```
// Get the meta values
$meta = get_post_meta($post_id,'',true);

// Now convert them to singles
$meta = array_map(function($n) {return $n[0];}, $meta);
```

Or, if you want to get really fancy, you can write your own "wrapper" around the get_post_meta function, like so:

```
function get_all_post_meta($post_id) {
    // Get the meta values
    $meta = get_post_meta($post_id,'');

    // Now convert them to singles and return them
    return array_map(function($n) {return $n[0];}, $meta);
}
```

Which you could then use like so:

```
$meta = get_all_post_meta($post_id);
```

Or, if you aren't on PHP 5.3+ (you should be!), you could do it like so:

```
function get_all_post_meta($post_id) {
    // Get the meta values
    $meta = get_post_meta($post_id,'');

    foreach($meta AS $key => $value) {
        $meta[$key] = $value[0];
    }

    return $meta;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is no way to get single value in get_post_meta when $single is true. So you write a custom function to get it.

Use

```
//callback to get single value in get_meta_data
function get_single_value($val) {
    return $val[0];
}

$meta = get_post_meta($post_id,'', true);
$meta1 = array_map('get_postmeta_single_value', $meta);
print_r($meta1);
```